# MySQL: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE works not with primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I want to update a MySQL row, when the primary already exists. The problem is that the query updates nothing on second execution.

The table-structure:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE Testtable;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| test_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| test_varchar | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| test_text    | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The query:

```
INSERT INTO `Testtable`(`test_id`, `test_varchar`, `test_text`) VALUES ('1', 'hello', 'hello world!') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `test_id` = '1';
```

Result of first execution:

> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

Result of second execution:

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

I don't understand why are 0 rows affected, because in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) it says:

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or **PRIMARY KEY**, MySQL
>   performs an UPDATE of the old row.

Yeah, I have a primary key as you can see in the structure, but I don't understand why are 0 rows affected. How to optimise the query that it will work? Do I need to specify all variables again in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`-part?

Comment: You have a row with test_id = 1. You're trying to insert a new row with a duplicate key, but the data you're trying to insert (test_id = 1) is no different than what's already there, so it doesn't need to update anything, therefore no records are being affected.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski So you mean to go sure I need to specify all variables again the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`-part?

Comment: If all your data is the same, you don't need to update anything.

If row 1's data was `1`, `hello`, and `HELLO`, you could to ...`ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` and set `test_varchar` to `goodbye` instead.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, **and
>   0 if an existing row is set to its current values**.